# Xpath with Namespaces

Tags: soap, xpath, namespaces

I am not able to get the result for the following xpath query .

**Code is given below**

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/reservationresponse.xml"));

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         
        DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

        
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath1 = factory.newXPath();
       
        NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() { 
            public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                
            String uri = null; 
            if (prefix.equals("SOAP-ENV")) 
            uri = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; 
            else if (prefix.equals("header")) 
            uri = "http://wsi.nat.qt.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/"; 
            else if (prefix.equals("S18")) 
                uri = "http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01";  
            else if (prefix.equals("S18")) 
                uri = "http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01";
            else if (prefix.equals("SOAP-ENC")) 
                uri = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";
            else if (prefix.equals("xsi")) 
                uri = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            else if (prefix.equals("xsd")) 
                uri = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
            else if (prefix.equals("S2")) 
                uri = "http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/CCM/Agreements";
            else if (prefix.equals("S16")) 
                uri = "http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/MTOSI";
            else if (prefix.equals("S8")) 
                uri = "http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/MTOSI/Structs";
            else if (prefix.equals("S11")) 
                uri = "http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/NonCCM";
            //uri = null
            System.out.println(uri);
            return uri; 
            } 
            public Iterator getPrefixes(String val) { 
            return null; 
            } 
            // Dummy implemenation - not used! 
            public String getPrefix(String uri) { 
            return null; 
            } 
            }; 

        xpath1.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
        XPathExpression expr = xpath1.compile("//SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-       ENV:Body/S18:reserveResourceResponse/header:standardHeader/header:e2e/header:E2EDATA/text()         ");

   Object result = expr.evaluate(xmlDocument);
    System.out.println("********** &&&&&&&&&" + result);
```

**XML for parsing :**
This is the xml i am trying to parse

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:header="http://wsi.nat.qt.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <S18:reserveResourceResponse
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01 ManageResourceServiceInterface.20090501.xsd"
        xmlns:S18="http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01"
        xmlns:S2="http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/CCM/Agreements"
        xmlns:S16="http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/MTOSI"
        xmlns:S8="http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/MTOSI/Structs"
        xmlns:S11="http://capabilities.nat.qt.com/xsd/ManageResourceService/2009/05/01/NonCCM">
        <header:standardHeader>
            <header:e2e>
                <header:E2EDATA>10=2pzmw0etdv,1=2pzmwi65s6,7=apl08929imbwa2,6=PCK002069,4=RoBTESB-default,9=wlsuser,15=RoBTESB,8=UNKNOWN,1.2=APP10865:2pzmwi65s6:,1.1=APP10865:2pzmw0esr0:,16=LIMS
                </header:E2EDATA>
            </header:e2e>
```

Result is empty

Comment: The xml snippet is given below

Comment: Your XML is invalid. Please post a valid snippet you're having problems with. Anyway, why is there whitespace in the middle of your query, right in `/SOAP-       ENV:Body/`?